# More Efficient way to avoid two for-loops and combine them into one?

Tags: java, for-loop

Basically, I got this:

(`path` is a String Array)

```
    String writer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        writer += path[i] + "{";
    }
    writer += string;
    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        writer += "}";
    }
```

But this looks ugly and inefficient. Is there any way to properly combine this into only one for-loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Is it a code block generator? Explain the purpose of the loops or we can't help you.

Comment: What is inefficient here is not the two loops. It's string concatenation. Use a StringBuilder. Using foreach loops would make it less ugly, too.

Comment: It'll help if you let us in on what exactly you're trying to achieve... There is no exact way to use two for loops; it all depends on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no smart means, the following has more speed:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String p : path) { // Might cost a bit of speed.
    sb.append(p).append('{');
}
sb.append(string);
for (int i = 0; i < path.length; ++i) {
    sb.append('}');
}
String writer = sb.toString();
```

In one loop:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
for (int i = path.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    sb.insert(0, '{');
    sb.insert(0, path[i]);
    sb.append('}');
}
String writer = sb.toString();
```

Comment: There are still two loops though

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution without a `for`-loop and with the usage of `StringBuilder` instead of `+=`-constructs which can lead to memory- and performance problems.

```
StringBuilder firstPart = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder lastPart = new StringBuilder();

Arrays.stream(path)
    .forEach(elem -> {
        firstPart.append(elem);
        firstPart.append("{");
        lastPart.append("}");
    });

firstPart.append(string);
firstPart.append(lastPart.toString());
String writer = firstPart.toString();
```